# PowerPC: what does 0 / 0 do when floating point exceptions are disabled?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, powerpc

I don't have access to a physical PowerPC system but am writing an emulator for the 603e model. The programming manual describes the floating point exception model in some detail but is unclear about what result is produced during an invalid floating point operation (namely 0 / 0 and the square root of a negative number). I thought that the IEEE spec mandated 0 / 0 to be a NaN and the PowerPC documentation seems to imply that a QNaN would be generated if floating point exception processing is disabled.

But I have reason to suspect it may actually be either writing 0 or leaving the destination unaltered.

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Until somebody with a real ppc comes by, maybe just check another emulator, e.g. qemu. Edit: I have looked at [qemu source](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/target/ppc/fpu_helper.c#L180), it does seem to write a `QNaN`.

Comment: I thought divide by zero was to result in a properly signed infinity, now zero over zero is perhaps a specific case.  I would hope it does what the IEEE spec says which means remove the PPC or any other target from your question.

Comment: Looking at the [Power ISA 2.07](https://openpowerfoundation.org/?resource_lib=ibm-power-isa-version-2-07-b), pg 126, you should get a QNaN. But that is a bit more modern than the 603e.

Another source to look at would be the manual for the Freescale e300 which is advertised as backwards compatible with the old 603e. [Their manual](http://www.nxp.com/assets/documents/data/en/reference-manuals/e300coreRM.pdf) might give more information, but I can't find anything obvious.

Comment: @old_timer - yes, 0/0 is an invalid operation rather than a simple divide by zero. The manual (which claims IEEE-compliance for this stuff) claims to write a QNaN.

Comment: The IEEE standard requires a quiet NaN as the result of 0/0. For exact emulation, you still need to find out the specific bit pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, everyone! Indeed, 0/0 should be a QNaN according to the IEEE spec and this is what happens on every other platform I've dealt with. I'm increasingly sure this is indeed the case on PowerPC, too, and the problem that led me to this question is actually not related to my emulation of the division instructions!